# R vector loose one component when passed

Tags: r

```
recursiveCall <- function(x, N)
{
    cat("length = ", length(x))
    cat("vector x = ", x[1:2^N], "\n")
    return (x)
}
PaulLevyBrownianMotion <- function(N)
{
    cat("Paul Levy construction for N = ", N, "\n")
    W = c(rnorm(2^N+1, 0, 1))
    cat("length = ", length(W))
    cat("Wstandard = ", W, "\n")
    W <- recursiveCall(W[1:2^N+1], N)
    return (W) 
}
```

My vector W seems to lost its first component when passed to another function. Could you help me with this ? Here is the output.

```
> W = PaulLevyBrownianMotion(2)
Paul Levy construction for N =  2 
length =  5Wstandard =  0.08641454 1.616638 -0.8747996 0.6149899 0.2689501 
length =  4vector x =  1.616638 -0.8747996 0.6149899 0.2689501 
>
```

Comment: It's probably because the colon operator `:` takes precedence over `+`.  Try using brackets in your construction of `W[1:(2^N+1)]`

Comment: @Andrie: d'oh, simulpost. Confirmed in R.

Comment: I'm wondering why you do not use the R function `Recall`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`W[1:2^N + 1]` isn't indexing what you think because of precedence. First the vector `1:2^N` is constructed and then scalar `1` is added (so each element is incremented by one), resulting in elements 2 through the end being selected.

Comment: so I guess I have to write as Andrie said, being W[1:(2^N+1)]. Thanks a lot for all your answers I will try it right now.

Comment: Correct, Andrie's solution will index the elements you want. For the specific case you've posted, actually, just passing `W` would do as well because `W` is defined with length `2^N + 1`.